# Finding the parallel and perpendicular lines to Cartesian equations on a line (3d)

Tags: vectors

$L: x=\frac {y-1}{2}=\frac {z+1}{3}$

Decompose the vector $u = i − 2j + 2k$ into the sum of two vectors, where one is parallel to $L$ and the other is perpendicular to $L$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: im actually really stuck on where to start, as i ve never seen this kind of combination of different concepts

Comment: You can see this as an orthogonal sum decomposition of a subspace, but you need to change it a bit since your line is not a subspace. The general result is that if $W$ is a subspace, then every vector $z$ can be written as $w+w^{\perp}$, where $w^{\perp, } \in W^{\perp}, w \in W$, but your line does not go through the origin, but youcan translate it so that it does..

Comment: i have no idea what your saying in all honesty, could u dumb it down for me? thanks ( could be the notation )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we find the equation of $L$ in the form $L=tv+P$, for that we use the parameter $t$
$$t=x=\frac{y-1}{2}=\frac{z+1}{3} \Rightarrow x=t,y=2t+1,z=3t-1$$
So $L$ is of the form:
$$L=tv+(0,1,-1)\ \text{with}\ v=i+2j+3k$$
Now, you have $u=i-2j+2k$, and you want it to be the sum of one vector parallel to $L$ and one perpendicular to $L$. The parallel vector must be of the form $\lambda v$ and lets call the perpendicular one $w$. Now you have:
$$u=\lambda v+w$$
Multipliying the last equation by $v$:
$$u\cdot v=\lambda v\cdot v + w\cdot v$$
$$u\cdot v=\lambda v\cdot v + 0$$
$$\frac{u\cdot v}{v\cdot v}=\lambda$$
Upon substitution you get: 
$$\lambda = \frac{14}{3}, \lambda v=(\frac{14}{3}, \frac{28}{3}, 14), w=u-\lambda v = (\frac{-11}{3}, \frac{-34}{3}, -12).$$

Comment: i would upvote you if  i could, i appreciate the help. thanks alot

Comment: @tony don't worry, still you can accept my answer, just tick the check mark ;)

Comment: i think your conversion of cartesioan equation to parametric form is incorrect

Comment: @tony yes sorry for the mistake

Comment: if im not wrong, that dosent change the final answers does it?

Comment: @tony no because the error was on the point $P$ not on the vector

Comment: i think your subsitution is incorrect, as the u.v product should be 3 and v.v product should be 14. is it just inversed?

Answer (score 0):

Let $l$ be $(1,2,3)$ vector along the line and $x\perp l$,
let's rewrite the line's equation to $x=a+tl$, where $a=(0,1,-1)$ and $t$ such, that $\frac{x-0}{1}=\frac{y-1}{2}=\frac{z+1}{3}=t$
So $u=x+zl$ for some $z$.
$$x\perp l \Leftrightarrow x\cdot l=0$$
$$(u-zl)\cdot l=0$$
$$u\cdot l = z l\cdot l$$
$$z=\frac{u\cdot l}{l\cdot l}$$
Then substitute $z$ back, $x=u-\frac{u\cdot l}{l\cdot l}l$ is the perpendicular component to $l$, and $\frac{u\cdot l}{l\cdot l}l$ is the parallel one.

Comment: i would upvote u if i could but thanks alot